# Tangent space of algebraic variety over $\mathbb{C}$ and complex manifold

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a morphism of smooth varties over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $f^{an}:X^{an}\rightarrow Y^{an}$ be the induced morphism of complex manifolds, where $X^{an}=X(\mathbb{C})$, $Y^{an}=Y(\mathbb{C})$.

Now suppose $x\in X(\mathbb{C})$, which induces a morphism of zariski tangent spaces $df_x:T_{X,x}\rightarrow T_{Y,f(x)}$ (since $x$ and $f(x)$ are $\mathbb{C}-$rational points) and a morphism of manifold tangent spaces $df^{an}_x:T_{X^{an},x}\rightarrow T_{Y^{an},f^{an}(x)}$.

My question is: what is the relation between $df_x$ and $df^{an}_x$? More precisely, whether the following statemnt is true:

$df_x$ is an isomorphism (resp. injective, resp. surjective) $\Leftrightarrow$ $df^{an}_x$ is an isomorphism (resp. injective, resp. surjective).

Furthermore, if we remove the assumption $X$ and $Y$ are smooth (and then $X^{an}$ and $Y^{an}$ are complex analytic space), whether the above statament still holds?

Comment: Is the problem that, relation between $f$ is a morphism w.r.t Zariski topology and $f^{an}$ is a morphism w.r.t complex numbers default topology ? Is an algebraic variety also a manifold ?

Comment: I think the problem doesn't come from topology, since tangent  space is just a vector space. (By the way, I don't wnat to say an algebraic variety is a manifold since they belong to the different catgeory. Here we just know the manifold $X^{an}$ "comes from" $X$).

Comment: In local affine charts, $X$ and $Y$ are given by vanishing of polynomial, in particular holomorphic functions, and the tangent spaces, differentials etc are given by the same formulas in terms of derivatives of those polynomials and $f$ (or to be more precise the polynomial expression of $f$ in those local coordinates), so in that sense $df^{an}_x = df_x$. In particular the statement is true. If you remove the smoothness assumptions what is your definition of $T_{X^{an}, x}$?

Comment: I think the point is that the canonical map $\mathcal{O}_{X^{an},x} \to \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ (where $x$ is a closed point of $X$), while not an isomorphism, induces an isomorphism on completed local rings.

Comment: The standard reference for this would be either Serres GAGA paper or maybe SGA I, if you're more hardcore.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I found the reference in SGA1, P321,  Proposition 3.1